# API VoiceBase and upload audio

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, speech-recognition

Nice day
I intend to implement [Voicebase](https://www.voicebase.com/) somehow I already got the data of the audio that I uploaded the test, the next step is to upload audios through a form and the process is done through AJAX.

```
<form id="formFile">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="vb-file">Agregar Archivo:</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="media" name="media">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the ajax code is as follows

```
$('#formFile').submit(function(e) {

    var access_token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJh';

    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('formFile'));
    formData.append('dato', 'valor');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://apis.voicebase.com/v2-beta/media',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token );
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
    });


    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I need to replace the following code and put it as ajax, especially the part of the language because the file already rises without problems as I mentioned.

```
curl https://apis.voicebase.com/v2-beta/media  \
    --form media=@recording.mp3 \
    --form 'configuration={
      "configuration": {
        "language": "es-LA",
        "keywords": {
          "semantic": false
        },
        "topics": {
          "semantic": false
        }
      }
    }' \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}"
```

Comment: You need a submit button for your form

Comment: I´m sorry Thank you, I added it was an error not to write, but that is not the main problem.

Comment: If you use Chrome, enable your "Developer Tools" (Mozilla  Firefox has something similar). You can then see what you are sending and receiving in the HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are missing the configuration JSON file in your request. In the cURL request, there is an element that begins:'configuration={ "configuration ..."' This configuration is necessary for v2-beta to understand how to process the media file you are uploading. 
You may create a config.json file and upload this in addition to the media file in a heading by creating another element in formData called 'configuration' and attaching the configuration.json.

You want something like:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("media", "my_media_file.mp3");
formData.append("configuration", "configuration.json");

var settings = {
  "url": "https://apis.voicebase.com/v2-beta/media",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Bearer access_token"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": formData
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

And your configuration.json file should contain:

```
configuration={
  "configuration": {
    "language": "es-LA",
    "keywords": {
      "semantic": false
    },
    "topics": {
      "semantic": false
    }
  }
}
```

By the way: Thank you for not posting your full access token! Access tokens should be regarded as the equivalent of user name and password together - and shouldn't be shared.

Comment: Thank you Daniel O'Rorke, I will try it.